# What is the correct punctuation of e.g. when used with a single example?

Tags: punctuation

After e.g. do you always put a comma even if the example is only one thing? DO you write e.g., chicken soup or e.g. chicken soup? 
My question refers explicitly to using just a singular example.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on context. I would punctuate it exactly as if I were writing 'for example', which is what it means.

**Without comma**
'When most people buy groceries, e.g. eggs, they always check the price.'

**With comma.**
'The major changes in crime patterns of the last twenty years present challenges to police morale. E.g., the reduction in burglary and street crime in the large cities necessitates a corresponding reduction in police manpower.'

Comment: I was thaught that the use of _e.g.:_ was also allowed. Is this true? For example, "_e.g.: 'This is some tet that acts as the example given', 'This is another example'_."

Comment: I'd probably put a comma in your first example: _When most people buy groceries (e.g., eggs) they always check the price._ I agree with your answer in principle; the hard part is coming up with an example where we wouldn't put a comma after _for example_. Perhaps at the end of a sentence? _There are a few key ingredients for a truly memorable day: weather, food, and company, e.g._

Comment: @J.R. I don't think I would actually put an 'e.g.' at the end of a sentence in that way. I would feel compelled to write 'for example'. But perhaps that's just me. I agree, however, that 'e.g. eggs' should perhaps have a comma. though I also agree it is difficult to think of an example that doesn't need one.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe I see no reason why one can't, and should in appropriate circumstances use 'e.g.:'.

Comment: @WS2 - I agree that the "e.g." looks a bit awkward at the end. Like you, I was twisting things around trying to find a good example (which I suppose means it's safe to say that we'd **usually** use a comma).